# I want transparent UIView but not the elements which I added over it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, background, transparent

First of all sorry for the Title. I didn't knew how to exactly convey my problem. So my problem is that I have set black color in the background of a UIView and I've made it transparent. But the UI elements which I am adding over it (e.g Buttons, Labels etc) is also getting faded along with the UIView. For example if I set the alpha of UIView to be 0.5 then it automatically applies to all the controls I've added on that UIView which I don't want. So please tell me how to save elements from getting faded.

Comment: don't set alpha for the view, set it's color like [UIColor clearColor] as view background, the full instruction would be like [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like:

`view.backgroundColor=[[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];`

This will keep the transparency solely to the background but not the subviews.

Comment: `UIColor` has a lot of convenience methods those pretty much enough for your needs (which are also cached). No need to alloc init.

Comment: Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

If you just have to make `view` transparent not the `subviews`, then go with

```
self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
```

What it does is, it will make background `view` transparent, instead setting alpha property will fade `subviews` also.

Answer (score 1):

instead of writing in code. we can set it in Interface Builder also. By selecting the background color in the Attributes Inspector in the IB you have to click on background color property and select other and there you can set the alpha or any color you want directly which reduces the code.[image: See here]

@Rahul

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is, don't change the `alpha` of the `UIView`, instead, set `backgroundColor` with the desired transparency, e.g. if you want to have half transparent black, do `view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0. alpha:.5];`

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you so much your answer . It worked perfectly but @GYan has answered it first that's why I am accepting his answer. But Thank you so much for your time :)